# Replace custom filter in web.xml to Security Filter Chain

Tags: java, spring-security

In my initial implementation I have simple filter definition in `web.xml` and it's work fine for me.

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>myCustomFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>some.package.MyCustomFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myCustomFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My goal is replace filter that above to spring security.
I already added `springSecurityFilterChain` according to spring documentation: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then I added `filterChainProxy` definition to my `spring-security.xml`

```
    <alias name="filterChainProxy" alias="springSecurityFilterChain"/>

    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
            <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
                <security:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="myCustomFilter"/>
            </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myCustomFilter" class="some.package.MyCustomFilter"/>
```

**Existing spring-security.xml configuration:**

```
    <security:http pattern="/**/*.some_extension" security="none"/>

    <security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="entryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="manager" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('SOME_ROLE')"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="map_filter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <security:logout
                logout-url="/my/logout.controller"
                delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                />
    </security:http>


    <util:map id="map_filter">
        <entry key="/my/first/login/.controller" value-ref="filter1"/>
        <entry key="/my/second/login/.controller" value-ref="filter2"/>
    </util:map>
```

Now, when I try to login, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/my/first/login/.controller', method 'POST'
```

Comment: 1.why you using both custom filterChainproxy and spring name space config ? 2. If you are using spring name space and want different cutom-filters at position FORM_LOGIN_FILTER for different urls, you can define multiple http elements